# Code to transfer values based on column header

Tags: excel, vba, header, cell

We have an Excel sheet that has column headers MIC and Version.
Sheet1:

```
SCRNHYF1                SCRNRBF1                SCRNEBF1            
MIC Version Lower Limit Upper Limit MIC Version Lower Limit Upper Limit MIC Version Lower Limit Upper Limit
50015357    1   95  100 50015357    1   95  100 50015359    1   90  100
50015358    1   0   100 50015358    1   0   100 50015360    1   0   100
50014016    3   95  100 50014016    3   95  100 50014016    1   90  100
50010606    2   0   100 50010606    2   0   100 50010606    15  0   100
50000779    3   95  100 50000779    3   95  100 50000779    16  90  100
50010608    2   0   100 50010608    2   0   100 50010608    15  0   100
50150795    1   95  100 50150795    1   95  100 50150795    2   90  100
50150796    1   0   100 50150796    1   0   100 50150796    2   0   100
```

I would like VBA code to rearrange data in sheet1 to sheet2 as shown below.
Please note: We have these MIC and Version header repeat many times in sheet1.
Sheet2:

```
RoS MIC Ver
SCRNHYF1    50015357    1
SCRNHYF1    50015358    1
SCRNHYF1    50014016    3
SCRNHYF1    50010606    2
SCRNHYF1    50000779    3
SCRNHYF1    50010608    2
SCRNHYF1    50150795    1
SCRNHYF1    50150796    1
SCRNRBF1    50015357    1
SCRNRBF1    50015358    1
SCRNRBF1    50014016    3
SCRNRBF1    50010606    2
SCRNRBF1    50000779    3
SCRNRBF1    50010608    2
SCRNRBF1    50150795    1
SCRNRBF1    50150796    1
SCRNEBF1    50015359    1
SCRNEBF1    50015360    1
SCRNEBF1    50014016    1
SCRNEBF1    50010606    15
SCRNEBF1    50000779    16
SCRNEBF1    50010608    15
SCRNEBF1    50150795    2
SCRNEBF1    50150796    2
```

my code so far...which is not working..

```
Sub CopyRng()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Col As Long

On Error Resume Next    

Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set Rng = WS1.Range("E1:E25")    

With WS2

    Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS1.Range("E1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
'Writes the values to the last empty cell from the bottom of the column:
    .Cells(.Rows.count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.count).Value = Rng.Value


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What's stpopping you from creating that code? Which *exact* part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Please help me with my code correction.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` - what happens? If you get an error, what is it?

Comment: Run time error 1004:Unable to get the match property of the Worksheet class function

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case where `Match()` fails: I prefer to drop the `.Worksheetfunction` and test the return value to see if it's an error.

```
Sub CopyRng()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Col 

Set WS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set Rng = WS1.Range("E1:E25")    

With WS2

    Col = Application.Match(WS1.Range("E1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
    If Not IsError(Col) Then
         'Writes the values to the last empty cell from the bottom of the column:
         .Cells(.Rows.count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
                       Resize(Rng.Rows.count).Value = Rng.Value

    Else
         msgbox "Not found!"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm attaching actual spread sheet. Not able to paste values as per the client requirement. Any help greatly appreciated. Link to my excel sheet:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzfhr-9EkKsxU0JhZkJrSXVmU2c/edit?usp=sharing